# Get the pids launched by a command

Tags: macos, bash, pid

I am running Mac OS X Yosemite.

I am trying to return the PIDs started by a command launch using a background process style. (`myCommand &`)

To get them I found `$!` which return the PID of the last running process.

Or something like `pgrep -f "elm"`  which return all the pid with `elm` in the command line.

I am wondering if there is a another way to get the PIDs started by a command. Because, I have some programs starting severals processes and `$!` only return the last one and using `pgrep` could return PID started by another command that the one I want to target.

Edit:

How to get the list of the PIDs started by a command ?

Edit 2:

[image: State of the PIDs]

Edit 3:

[image: Parents]

Comment: ... what exactly is your question?

Comment: you answered your own question INSIDE of your question.

Comment: "I have some programs starting severals PIDs " - how are they started ? if they are started one after the other, you can get the $! after each of them, no ? putting a sample of your code would help probably

Comment: @specializt why remove unix tag since bash is unix based?

Comment: BTW I think you mean "I have some programs starting severals processes" instead; the PID is the Process ID, the number of this process; it is not the process itself, just a unique identifier

Comment: @farialima yes I mean processes and not PID.

They are started by a command line program "elm-reactor" which launch two pocesses when executed. I don't how he launch then as it's an external program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pidof`.

```
pidof command
```

OR

```
pidof program
```

OR

```
pidof [options] program1 program2 ... programN
```

Comment: It's only returning 1PIDs not the 2 created.

Comment: See the edit. I used ps before and after launching the program.

Comment: You can pass more than one program to `pidof`.

Comment: Yes, we can but the problem is I have to know all the program name before. It's not really easy to scale. And if one day it's start more programs, it's need some hard coded information to patch it.

Thanks for the proposition, if I don't find anything better I will take it :) But I would prefer of most scalable way.

Comment: Is `elm-reactor` the parent process of `elm-reactor-unwrapped`?

Comment: See Edit 3.Looks like yes. I probably should test if there are some child and get their PID.

Comment: In that case, if you determine the pid of `elm-reactor`, you can pass that along to `pgrep -P ppid` which will list all the pid of the child processes of that parent.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will go with this solution :)